# Getting value from directive for future use

Tags: angular, typescript

I’m trying to get a toolbar fixed in the bottom of the window but other component keeps getting on top of it when I scroll down. The solution I came up with, was getting the height of the toolbar, and giving the “other component” THAT value in margin/padding bottom. So it will never get on top of it.

**get-height-directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '../../../../node_modules/protractor';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appGetHeight]'
})

export class GetHeightDirective implements OnInit{
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let styles = getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement);
    console.log(styles.height);
  }

}
```

I applied that directive into this:

**where-to-apply-directive.html**

```
    <div appGetHeight class="col">
      <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto ipsum repellat illum corporis, possimus consequatur qui nisi ipsa in. Molestiae, dolor. Fugit, eum quas. Provident neque id optio facilis velit.</p>
    </div>
```

With this I get the height of the toolbar in a `console.log` that says something like `66.8px`. I want to use that '100px' now to style the margin-bottom of an element of a sibling component but I couldn't find any solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please explain the sentence " but other component keeps getting on top of it when I scroll down." a bit more. You might consider using the css - property  z-index with position fixed to be sure that your component is on top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get access to the instance of a directive consider using the exportAs variable. 
You can do some further reading here:

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26

**Summary:** 
With export as you get the possibility to gain access to the directive of a component. 
To gain such an access you need to add exportAs to the @Directive Decorator and give it a name.

To save the directive to a variable of the parent - view you can use the following syntax:

Here an example with your code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appGetHeight]',
  exportAs: 'heightDirective'
})
export class GetHeightDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  public styles: CSSStyleDeclaration;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.styles = getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement);
    console.log(this.styles.height);
  }

}
```

**Note:**

1. I changed styles to this.styles otherwise the variable will be deleted after ngOnInit as let is a block-scoped variable.
2. Take a look at "exportAs" on the third line.

Usage:

```
<div appGetHeight #varWithDirective="heightDirective">Test</div>

<div class="login-background" [style.margin-bottom]="varWithDirective.styles.height" >
```

Please note here the #varWithDirective="heightDirective" the heightDirective has to represent the exportAs name. 
Then I have access to all values of the directives within the variable #varWithDirective.

I hope this helps you.

**Important:** That what you are asking for can defeinitly be solved with a different approach. It is bad practice to solve CSS problems with JavaScript. 
But for that I would need more information.

Consider using: z-index / position fixed and perhaps css-grid.

Comment: This is correct. I used this and could modify the `margin-bottom` property with the directive height result from `getComputedStyle`. Nevertheless I think you are right about considering modifying my css and not resolving this with javascript. I have a mess cause i'm using bootstrap + angular material. So what i wanted to modify was a `mat-toolbar` (angular material) inside a `container>row>col` (bootstrgap), so I'm sure there are some css conflicts in there. I'll try another approach. **Nevetheless, this resolved my immediate problem**. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Simple `@Output` and others can subscribe to the change.
2. Create a service, like `AppHeightService`. Create a `Subject` component variable in it which will emit the computed height to everybody who subscribed to it. To notify the service from directive, simply create a function in the service like: `emitHeight`(height: string). In this function you can call next on subject with this value.

Comment: I need further study in angular to try this approach. I think maybe I'll try this when I get into services lectures in my courses. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with css. Let's say you have a header of 100px and a footer of 50px.

Then you can set the height of the div in css with

```
height: calc(100vh - 150px);
```

That will calculate 100 units of the viewport height and substract de 150px of the header and footer.

Note :

vh = Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

Viewport = the browser window size.

Comment: This didn't worked i my case. My html file is a mess i think. What i'm trying to modify is an angular material element, inside a container>row>col from bootstrap. Thanks anyway for your answer. I'm sure it works in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

**get-height-directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '../../../../node_modules/protractor';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appGetHeight]'
})

export class GetHeightDirective implements OnInit{
  styles;
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.styles = getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement);
    console.log(this.styles.height);
  }

}
```

**Toolbar HTML:**

```
<div appGetHeight>Test</div>
```

You can use appGetHeight directive to compute the style of the toolbar.

You can also create another directive 'ScrollerDirective' which needs to be attached in the component Template div tag which enables scrollbar in the UI.

**ScrollerDirective:**

```
import {GetHeightDirective} from './get-height.directive';
@ViewChild(GetHeightDirective) getHeightDir;

@HostListener('window:scroll', [$event]) scrolling(event){
    console.log('scrolling');
    console.log(this.getHeightDir);
}
```

Using ViewChild, you can access getHeight directive and its public properties. You can listen scroll events using HostListener.

Comment: I didn't understand how this could solve my problem. Sorry.